# Android: installing library on eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, listview

I'm not able to install SwipeListView(https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) properly on my project. The `src` folder is empty and even if I copy the classes under `java` folder it still doesn't get it right. I followed some instructions on the web (specifically TuteCenter.com) but didn't work either.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is a gradle module, as the README says.

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Use gradle or make a new module from its sources using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

That library is actually a gradle project, used in android studio. if you want to import it in eclipse, you need to import this folder: 'android-swipelistview / swipelistview / src / main'